# Alignment issues inside a formpanel

Tags: extjs

Team,

I am facing one problem where I am not able to aligh text boxes inside form panel. basically I want 2 columns layout inside inner panel

Basically I am creating one formpanel and inside that I am planning to create 3 more panels but text boxes are always coming in newline.

code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World Window</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ext-3.4.0/resources/css/ext-all.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/adapter/ext/ext-base.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-3.4.0/ext-all.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    Ext.onReady(function(){
        var tab2 = new Ext.FormPanel({
            labelAlign: 'top',
            title: 'formname',
            bodyStyle:'padding:5px',
            width: 1200,
            height:600,
            items: [{
                xtype:'panel',
                plain:true,
                border:false,
                activeTab: 0,
                height:50,
                autoScroll:true,
                items:[{
                title:'Personal Details',
                defaults: {width: 230},
                layout:'form',
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                    items: [

                        {
                            fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                            name: 'first',
                            allowBlank:false,
                            value: 'Jack'
                        },{
                            fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                            name: 'last',
                            value: 'Slocum',

                        },{ 
                            xtype:'combo',
                            fieldLabel: 'Company',
                            name: 'company',
                            value: 'Ext JS'
                        }, {
                            fieldLabel: 'Email',
                            name: 'email',
                            vtype:'email'
                        }]

                }]
                }],
            buttons: [{
            text: 'Save'
            },{
            text: 'Cancel'
            }]
        });

    tab2.render(document.body); 


});
</script> 

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

With ExtJS 4 you don't need to use a form layout to manage field labels: you can use every layout container to layout the fields in your form (check this http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/upgrade).
So try to use a column layout for the FormPanel and then add 2 sub containers, each with vbox layout to manage your desired columns:

```
new Ext.FormPanel({
        layout: 'column',
        items: [
        {
           xtype:'container',
           columnWidth: .5,
           layout: 'vbox',
           items: [
           put here left column items
           ]
        },
        {
           xtype:'container',
           layout: 'vbox',
           columnWidth: .5,
           items: [
           put here right column items
           ]
        }
    });
```

Comment: I am using EXT JS 3.4 sorry for not updating it initially. Any way we can do in 3.4?

Comment: With ExtJS4 it is not recommend to instantiate by using `new` (in most situations)

Comment: is there way we can achieve this in EXTJS 3

Comment: See edited answer. To use it on ExtJS 3.x, you should comment the line with "layout: 'vbox'"

Comment: See edited answer. To use it on ExtJS 3.x, you should comment the line with "layout: 'vbox'"

Answer (score 1):

This is working inside a TabPanel with ExtJS 3.4:

```
// p is the tabPanel
t = p.add ({
    xtype: 'form',
    layout: 'column',
    items: [
        {
            xtype:'container',
            columnWidth: .5,
            frame: false,
            items: new Ext.Panel ({
                frame: false,
                bodyCssClass: 'x-panel-mc',
                bodyStyle: 'background-color: white',
                layout: 'form',
                items: formPart
            }),
        }, {
            xtype:'container',
            columnWidth: .5,
            items: buttonPart,
        }
    ],
});
```